# MTS Mblaze installation error in 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I have newly installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop, I could not connect MTS Mblaze to it. Offline message is shown in box.

I am requesting to **provide complete installation steps to connect MTS.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You’d have to install the package USB-ModeSwitch. It is available here : http://packages.debian.org/sid/usb-modeswitch

   Note : When you open the above link, you should check out its dependencies and also install the dependency package "usb-modeswitch-data".

   Just download and double-click on it to install the package.
2. After you’ve installed "usb-modeswitch" and "usb-modeswitch-data" packages, reboot your computer.
3. Connect the Mblaze Modem and wait for 30 seconds. While you’re waiting, the usb-modeswitch package is doing magic in the background, you can check the status through the following command:

   ```
   dmesg
   ```
4. I hope you have 'wvdial' pre-installed on your system. You can check that by typing 'wvdial' and see if the computer recognizes it. If it doesn’t then you have to install it. Its easy, refer this link (http://acomelectronics.com/GeorgeVita/restore_wvdial.html).
5. Now edit the file `/etc/wvdial.conf` (If it doesn’t exists, then create it) as Root and copy paste the following code :

   ```
   [Dialer cdma]
   Stupid Mode = 1
   Inherits = Modem0
   Password = mts
   Username = internet@internet.mtsindia.in
   Phone = #777

   [Modem0]
   Init1 = ATZ
   SetVolume = 0
   Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
   Baud = 115200
   FlowControl = Hardware (CRTSCTS)
   Dial Command = ATDT
   ```

   Note that ttyUSB0 may be different for your system. However, first try with the above code, if it doesn’t works and says some error like "ttyUSB0 doesn’t exists" or something similar to it, then find out the actual one by going through the output of following command :

   ```
   dmesg | grep -e "modem" -e "tty"
   ```
6. That’s it, you’re done. Now start browsing with the following command :

   ```
   wvdial cdma
   ```

As soon as you start seeing some IP addresses, you’re online! DO NOT close the terminal in which you executed the command, otherwise you will get disconnected.

And from next time, you don’t have to it all over again. Simply connect your modem, wait for 30 seconds and type the last command. To disconnect, goto the terminal, and press Ctrl + C

Comment: Probably you have to be a root to connect, so if 
wvdial cdma
doesn't work then use 
sudo wvdial cdma

Comment: Thanks for your very instant reply. I have some clarification on this, I am not connected to Internet then how come i download " usb-modeswitch and usb-modeswitch-data packages".

Comment: if you are not connected then how are you online on this site??

Comment: download this file from some other system connected to the network, put it in your pen drive and then in your 12.04

Comment: You don't need to install `usb-modeswitch` those packages are installed in Ubuntu by default. BTW, You have included line numbers in your code, which is very confusing.

Comment: sorry about formatting error :P. I am very bad at it, specially it doesn't work(that ctrl+K thing) while commenting

Comment: @vipin8169 I know that the question sounds silly, yet i wanted to know any other way is there for it. Ok i will tyr the steps and get back to you if i face any problem.

Comment: as per anwar you dont need to install this usb-modeswitch, so try once without doing that.